# streamwriter does not save unicode files correctly

Tags: c#, unicode, streamwriter

I'm opening a text file and removing the first line to prepare it for importing in a database using bulk insert. Here is my code:

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (var sr = new StreamReader("F:\\Upload\\File.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile,true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Substring(0, 8) != "Nr. Crt.")
                sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}

System.IO.File.Delete("F:\\Upload\\File.txt");
System.IO.File.Move(tempFile, "F:\\Upload\\File.txt");
```

After this if I open the resulting file, Unicode characters are replaced with other characters. For example strings containing non-breaking space (unicode U+00A0): `Value`  (note the unicode char ) are transformed in `Valueï¿½` .

How can I avoid this?

Edit:

Notepad++ is set to 'Encode in UTF-8'
Here is a picture of how it looks :

[image]

Comment: What are you opening the file in? Are you sure that it's not the software reading it back?

Comment: @rudi_visser It's not a display error, I have tried with notepad, notepad++, also when inserting in database it's the same incorrect value.

Comment: And Notepad++ is reading in UTF8 mode? Sorry just trying to make sure because I've recently written Unicode chars to files using virtually the exact same method and it's worked fine.

Comment: lulian notepad, notepad++ etc still need to know what the format is... have you tried including a BOM?

Comment: Yes, notepad++ isn't psychic, and this is exactly what I'd expect as per Marc's answer below.

Comment: How sure are your that `Upload\\File.txt` _is_ UTF8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> are transformed in Valueï¿½

The byte values for those 3 odd characters are 0xef 0xbd 0xbf.  Which is the utf8 encoding for codepoint \ufffd, the [replacement character �](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character).  Which is used when *reading* utf encoded text and the text contains an invalid encoding byte sequence.

Pointing squarely at an issue with File.txt, it was probably not encoded in utf-8.  If you have no idea what encoding was used for that file then the first guess is to pass Encoding.Default to the StreamReader constructor.

Comment: Looks like my file wasn't encoded in UTF-8. I'm receving this file from another application and it should be UTF-8.Anoter example of why you should never trust user input.Setting encoding to Default solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like it is writing fine, but the tool you are reading with is not expecting UTF-8. In many cases, you need to explicitly tell the tool what encoding to expect. However, a common approach is to prepend a BOM ("byte order mark"). This is simple - just use `new UTF8Encoding(true)` as the encoding and it will happen automatically. In tools that *don't* expect a BOM this will display as a few mangled chars at the start - but most modern tools will know what it means, and will switch to UTF-8 automatically. The point is: the BOM for UTF-8, UTF-16 LE and UTF-16 BE etc are all slightly different, but recognisable. A more complete list is on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).